# Eigenvalues of Linear Operator given by Conjugation by an Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a review problem for comp/qual studying and I cannot figure it out.  The hint provided seems to give some intuition, but I don't see how it generalizes.

> Let $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$.  Let $V$ be the $n^2$-dimensional vectorspace of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the linear operator $T : V \to V$ given by $T(M) = A^{-1}MA$.  Find the eigenvalues of $T$.
>
> (Hint: reduce to the case where $A$ is a diagonal matrix).

I believe that in the diagonal case, an eigenvalue is $1$, but I don't see anymore.  Furthermore, I don't know how to generalize that.  I know that $A$ is diagonalizable because it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues and thus, $n$ distinct eigenvectors so that if $U$ is a matrix with all of the eigenvectors of $A$ as its columns, then $A = UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ along the diagonal.  Then $$T(M) = A^{-1}MA = (UDU^{-1})^{-1} M UDU^{-1} = UD^{-1}U^{-1} M UDU^{-1}.$$  I am not quite sure where to go from there though, or if this is even a good approach at all.  Can anyone point me in a good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix whose only non-zero entry is $e_{ij} = 1$.  Then $E_{ij}$ is an "eigenvector" of $T$, and there are $n^2$ linearly independent such matrices.

Now, let $T_A(M) = A^{-1}MA$. Note that if $A = SDS^{-1}$, then 
$$
T_A = (T_S)^{-1} \circ T_D \circ T_S
$$

Comment: That is **not** the case!!! We may have eigenvalues besides $1$. Do the matrix multiplication, write out the answer explicitly.  What is $T(E_{ij})$ if $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th diagonal entry of $D$?

The second part of the hint is indeed about generalizing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe I see the rest from here!